# Google Maps api v3 + canvas + chrome causes black boxes on youtube videos and map elements

Tags: windows, macos, google-chrome, canvas, google-maps-api-3

Im experiencing two problems..

**Problem 1**
This only happens on chrome on a mac, tried canary and older versions.. the rectangle is a `<canvas>` element.. here is a screenshot of it. It appears the black rectangles are where the marker would be. The marker is still clickable, just unable to see it.

[image]

**Problem 2**
I am getting a black box covering youtube videos that are embedded in the InfoBubble of google maps api v3. The black box typically goes away when you zoom in after clicking the marker icon.  **This only occurs on Chrome in windows.**

[image]

The development site i am referring to is located here: http://sgaz.mapitusa.com
Select `Health & Wellness and click on the red marker icon.`

I'm putting a bounty on this, as i can't get an answer and i need one in order to move this product into production status.

**Here is a GIST of the map code** https://gist.github.com/a5515bd0b0139185ea16

**here is a GIST of the map init code**  https://gist.github.com/4937a60d2402e99278b0

**Update:**
Here is the iframe code that embeds the youtube video:

```
<iframe width="246" height="125" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XFDtfg7RquI" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

The black box over the video is selectable in chrome -> inspect element and this is the HTML..

```
<embed width="100%" id="video-player-flash" height="100%" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="http://s.ytimg.com/yt/swfbin/watch_as3-vflTsQfnT.swf" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" bgcolor="#000000" flashvars="el=embedded&amp;fexp=904527%2C913102%2C913601&amp;is_html5_mobile_device=false&amp;allow_embed=1&amp;allow_ratings=1&amp;hl=en_US&amp;use_tablet_controls=0&amp;eurl=http%3A%2F%2Fsgaz.mapitusa.com%2F&amp;iurl=http%3A%2F%2Fi1.ytimg.com%2Fvi%2FXFDtfg7RquI%2Fhqdefault.jpg&amp;view_count=28&amp;probably_logged_in=1&amp;title=GermRid&amp;avg_rating=0&amp;video_id=XFDtfg7RquI&amp;length_seconds=89&amp;sendtmp=1&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;sk=abu5-utg87bNYJgjGarozMSmFFhRfpxwC&amp;use_native_controls=false&amp;rel=1&amp;playlist_module=http%3A%2F%2Fs.ytimg.com%2Fyt%2Fswfbin%2Fplaylist_module-vflDOq0Br.swf&amp;iurlsd=http%3A%2F%2Fi1.ytimg.com%2Fvi%2FXFDtfg7RquI%2Fsddefault.jpg&amp;jsapicallback=ytPlayerOnYouTubePlayerReady&amp;playerapiid=player1&amp;framer=http%3A%2F%2Fsgaz.mapitusa.com%2F">
```

Comment: Are you adding code that draws something in a canvas element? Can you post the code?

Comment: im not adding any code. Maps API V3 uses canvas to draw the markers onto the map. Im using a custom map icon that is a png file.

Comment: if you remove all other css on the page is the issue still there?

Comment: Can you please add a link to your map? Impossible to debug based on a screenshot.

Comment: http://sgaz.mapitusa.com

Comment: Ok I can find GermRid if I type it but not if I paste it right in, have you checked how the flash is being embedded? See if its using WMode transparent, that has caused me headaches in the past

Comment: I updated the original question with code, and steps to find GermRID directly without searching.

Comment: it uses the html5 player, not flash from what i've been told from the plugin developer.

Comment: If i zoom in after the popup is clicked the black box goes away over the youtube video.

Comment: Chrome Version 19.0.1084.36 beta on Mac, no black box as far as I can tell.  I can open marker pins and see the marker dialogs with the expected content.

Comment: Note that this isn't Google Maps.  I have the same problem with Leaflet / OpenStreetMaps.  This bug is in Chrome 18, 19 and 20.

Comment: i now only have the issue on chrome, windows and it only pertains to youtube videos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following style to your iFrames:
`iframe { -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0); }`
That fixed the problem for me in Chrome and Safari on Windows 7.

Comment: `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0)` seems to work just as well.

Answer (score 6):

You have a cross-domain scripting error, in Chrome on both OS's.

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL
>   http://sgaz.mapitusa.com/ from frame with URL
>   http://www.youtube.com/embed/XFDtfg7RquI. Domains, protocols and ports
>   must match.

You can use the (Experimental) JavaScript Player API for iframe embeds to circumvent this issue.
http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/iframe_api_reference.html

I also get the error

> Uncaught TypeError: Property 'focus' of object [object DOMWindow] is
>   not a function http://sgaz.mapitusa.com/ line 94

In chrome 17.0.9 on windows XP.

Comment: Fraser, thanks for the response.. ill check into the cross-domain issue to see if that could be the cause. the focus typeerror i can't replicate though. Running the same version of chrome on xp.

Comment: Fairly certain this is unrelated to the black box problem.  This appears to be a bug in Chrome on Mac (versions 18, 19 and 20), since they implemented hardware acceleration for canvas.  Similar (same?) bug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10439952

Comment: @desau that could be the cause of issue 1...looks like there is something funky going on with the canvas element for sure...