# canvas tag produces black block in chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, canvas

This is very frustrating. If I don't set the height and width of the canvas, canvas draws just fine, but when I do set the height and width I get back a black box. I've stripped my code down to an insane degree and can't find any problem. The canvas tag works great in FF and IE9.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('can1');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');   

canvas.width    = 280;  
canvas.height   = 270;

ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

Even just this destroys the canvas in google chrome. No matter how little I draw, if the height or width is set it fails. If I set the height or width with css instead, it produces a distorted result.

Any ideas?

UPDATE: I've discovered that if my canvas is small enough, it works in chrome. However I need a canvas that is 280x270 not 100x100

Comment: Your code does not apply any background color. Can you provide a page which gives an example of it? My test didn't show any background color. If hat's all you have, then there is another reason for your black background. I could imagine that you have got a CSS rule which sets the background of the canvas and you probably didn't notice. Have you checked it with Chrome Developer Tools?

Comment: I have. There is no rule setting a background color. The expected behavior here would be a transparent element with nothing in it. Which is what I get in FF and ie9.

Comment: OK, I set up a jsfiddle with a background color (set in CSS) http://jsfiddle.net/2dfyw/1/  I'm running Chrome 18.0 and it appears fine.

Comment: I think we will need to see the surrounding html to answer this. Your layout might be falling apart.

Comment: In the JSFiddle I can't see a black background, altough you set the canvas to 280x270px.

Comment: Ok so apparently this really is a chrome 18 problem. Here is another website I built. Previously working fine now showing the error. http://www.millenniumfac.com/fac/home/index

Comment: Can you please describe where you see the black box? I am using Chrome 18.0.1025.168m too and everything is alright.

Comment: there is supposed to be an airplane flying. Not a giant black stipe. It seems to not be the case in everyone's chrome.

Comment: Fairly sure this is a bug in Mac Chrome since they enabled hardware acceleration for Canvas 2d.  There seem to be a ton of bugs in their hardware accelerated code for canvas .. really seems not ready for prime time.  By the way, I see the exact same problem when trying to add a canvas node to a Leaflet / OpenStreetMaps layer.  Another person reported the same problem on SO in Google Maps.  This problem is still in Chrome Beta (19).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solution! For all animation use RequestAnimationFrame. Just worked on one of my projects!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution I found that may help a very small number of people is that Chrome is more specific with `context.fillStyle` compared to other browsers. The hex color code prefix `#` is required in Chrome in this situation.

Here is one method of adjusting the entire canvas background color to a solid color:

```
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');  // Selects the DOM's first canvas element
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');  // Look into the canvas context documentation
context.fillStyle = '#2f2f2f';  // Gives us a nice dark gray color
context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);  // Fills the entire canvas
```

I would like to add that it is good practice to always include `#` when using hex color codes. Just an old silly mistake I noticed when I looked back on an old project of mine.

[Here is the documentation for canvas context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D)